# Delete a single git branch created for multiple repositories

Tags: git, macos, github

I have multiple folders in a git repository.

I tried to create a single branch for all the repositories using the below command.

bee start <my_branch> -all

So how do i delete branch which i have created for muliple folder.
If i do - git branch -D <my_branch>, it only deletes a branch from one repositories/folder.

Comment: What's that `bee`? "*I have multiple folders in a git repository.*" The other way around as I can decipher the question — you have multiple git repositories in a folder, right?

Comment: bee is like git. Yes, there are multiple git repositories in a folder.